# AWS CloudFormation Create Route 53 Private Hosted Zone

Tags: amazon-vpc, amazon-route53, amazon-cloudformation

Hello and thanks in advance...

I'm leveraging AWS CloudFormation to automatically build up a VPC and Subnets etc.

I would like the CloudFormation template to create a Route 53 Private Hosted Zone for VPC, but it appears that the only option is to create Public Hosted Zones.  The syntax for public zones is as follows (within "Resources"):

```
"MyHostedZone": {
    "Properties": {
        "HostedZoneConfig": {
            "Comment": "Created by CloudFormation"
        },
        "Name": "subdomain.example.com"
    },
    "Type": "AWS::Route53::HostedZone"
}
```

Ref: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-route53-hostedzone.html#cfn-route53-hostedzone-name

I've read the API docs for creating a hosted zone, and it *seems* that the endpoint to create a Public & Private Hosted Zone are the same, but the differentiating factor being that creating a Private Hosted Zone includes a VPC ID and a Region.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to create a Private Hosted Zone using CloudFormation?  I noticed that CloudFormation has the ability to create a "Custom Resource" but the docs are relatively confusing.

- Is there a way to do it?
- Or, is making a Custom Resource the way to go?  If so, can you help build the Resource JSON that would call the correct API endpoint?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I've been waiting for this too. Looks like it was added a couple of weeks after your post, you can find more information in [this article](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-route53-hostedzone.html#cfn-route53-hostedzone-vpcs)

```
"DNS": {
  "Type": "AWS::Route53::HostedZone",
  "Properties": {
    "HostedZoneConfig": {
      "Comment": "My hosted zone for example.com"
    },
    "Name": "example.com",
    "VPCs": [{
      "VPCId": "vpc-abcd1234",
      "VPCRegion": "ap-northeast-1"
    },
    {
      "VPCId": "vpc-efgh5678",
      "VPCRegion": "us-west-2"
    }],
    "HostedZoneTags" : [{
      "Key": "SampleKey1",
      "Value": "SampleValue1"
    },
    {
      "Key": "SampleKey2",
      "Value": "SampleValue2"
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: It will be interesting if you add relevant information in the page you include, just in case it dissapears on the future.